# How do I get the RenderBody() output in two separate div tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have two `<div>` tags in my **_Layout** view design, where one is for mobile view and another is for desktop view. The design was done by somebody else and the appropriate view is loaded when viewed on mobile and desktop. I can't alter the design, but I need to get the **RenderBody()** in moth divisions, like

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="mobileView">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
  <div id="desktopView">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not allowed, we cannot call **RenderBody()** two times. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Thanks for any ideas :)

**EDIT:**
Below is how the view changes-

```
#mobileView{display:none}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
#desktopView{display:none}
#mobileView{display:block}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it is the good approach to render multiple `@RenderBody()` in one Layout. In this case work around is that you should make 2 layouts `_LayoutMobile` and `_LayoutDesktop` . aAt the runtime should replace the layout.i.e

```
@{
Layout =mobileView? "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMobile.cshtml":"~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDesktop.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Actually, the mode changes dynamically as we change the size of the browser. It happens automatically, may be some script written somewhere. So, how do I set the layout then ?